# Alternative to Eval() in JSON?

Tags: json, string, expression, processing, eval

I'm using Processing.js (JSON), and I'm trying to use the `eval` function. Instead, an error keep coming up, saying that eval can be harmful. I tried refreshing and `parseFloat('7 + 7')`, which wouldn't work. What I'm doing is: `eval('7 + 88');`. I'm wondering if there is an alternative to eval, and why can it be harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval is evil, you really shouldn't be using it because if someone injects harmful code into your application it will be executed anyway. If all you are wanting it for is simple addition (etc) you can write your own math parser. It isn't too difficult.

Comment: Okay, thanks! One question: I'm trying to figure out what makes it "evil". I tried to `eval`'s native code by using `println()` (debug port for ProcssingJS), but it returns `function(){ [native code] }`. So how to get Eval's native code?